# Install will not load: PHP does not have MYSQL installed

Tags: php, mysql, installation

I'm having trouble installing Wordpress on my Windows 2008 R2 server. I'm getting the message:

> **Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.**

To the best of my knowledge, I think I have installed the MYSQL server correct and correctly edited the PHP.INI file. The MYSQL server is installed and running and both of these are shown below in the screenshot.

[image: MySQL and PHP Install]

Can anyone advise me on why this might not be working correctly?

Comment: Have you tried restarting your web server?

Comment: I have yeah, same problem

Comment: In the php.ini, there is also a line that starts with "extension_dir=". Is that line commented out, and if not, what is the value is equal to?

Comment: I've got extension_dir = "c:\php\ext" and it's not commented out

Comment: Hmm, the only other thing I could think of is to create a file in the root directory called info.php, and paste <?php phpinfo(); ?> into that file, and when you load that file look for extension_dir and make sure it is the same as you mentioned above, and then look for any mention of mysql in that file