# Is the outdated PHP mysql extension a requirement for Wordpress 4.6?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a bit puzzled when I after some time did another Wordpress install.

I'm using a standard Apache + PHP 7 combination (even under version control) and after checking out 4.6.1 of Wordpress (the tagged version from the Github SVN mirror, the [official Git-ified version](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress)) the installer greets me in the second step with the obvious error message that the mysql extension is missing in the following form:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /wp-includes/wp-db.php:1561
>   Stack trace:
>   #0 /wp-admin/setup-config.php(276): wpdb->db_connect()
>   #1 {main} thrown in /wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1561`

I'm a bit puzzled that the current Wordpress version still is based on the (outdated) php-mysql extension.

Maybe I'm missing some configuration setting, even the origin Ezsql class was able to deal with different database backends ca. 15 years ago and as *wpdb* is forked from it, maybe there is still a leftover to use php-mysqli which is more common nowadays (and should have been straightforward to port to). But perhaps this is beating a dead horse, so I need some feedback for a better orientation.

It's just that from the error message it sounds like mysql is still required, however I hope that's not the whole truth. The [Wordpress system requirements](https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/) do not share any information about the required PHP extensions and from these documented requirements it is that I'm matching them perfectly.

I've been running *phpcompatinfo* to find out more and the result is mixed, it looks like that mysqli *is* supported (or at least could be an option):

```
Extensions Analysis https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress

    Extension  Matches REF        EXT min/Max PHP min/Max     PHP all 
    Core               Core       7.0.2       7.0.2                   
    PDO                PDO        5.1.0       5.1.0                   
[...]
    memcache           memcache   0.2         4.3.3                   
 C  mysql              user       5.2.3       5.2.3                   
 C  mysqli             user       5.0.0       5.0.0                   
 C  mysqlnd            user                   4.0.0                   
 C  openssl            user       5.3.0       5.3.2                   
[...]
    Total [41]                                7.0.2 => 5.6.23
```

Related questions:

- [Install will not load: PHP does not have MYSQL installed](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/166188/install-will-not-load-php-does-not-have-mysql-installed)
- [Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/190071/your-php-installation-appears-to-be-missing-the-mysql-extension-which-is-require)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WordPress will use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) when [it can](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4a6f90db58a935abb688cfb91b391dffeda7b35c/wp-includes/wp-db.php#L638-L646) or unless you tell it not to. Unfortunately if WP doesn't see a `mysqli_*` function, it will assume that you want to use `mysql_*`.

There [is some logic](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4a6f90db58a935abb688cfb91b391dffeda7b35c/wp-includes/wp-db.php#L1543-L1561) that will fall back to plain, old `mysql_*`, but, from your stack trace, that's not what's happening.

You don't mention what OS you're running on, but I'd guess that the `php70-mysql` package was not installed. Ubuntu and things like the [ondrej/php PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) won't include the various mysql drivers (pdo mysql and mysqli) by default.

Comment: The mysqli extension was missing, I added it to the container and now the setup continues. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what @chrisguitarguy said, `mysql` extension was deprecated at php 7.0 (or was it 5.6? not important here), in favor of `mysqli`extension. As chris said, wordpress tries to detect if you have `msqli` installed and use it, and in case the detection fails it will try to use `mysql`. The error you got indicates that you don't have `mysqli`installed or configured.